# Need help with Sorcerer build options

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, sorcerer

Ok, so I'm working on a Spellscale Sorcerer with a gambler theme; he will eventually be taking levels of Fatespinner and Fortune's Friend (he doesn't consider this cheating any more than an athlete working out to improve his strength would be cheating) and will probably be more of a support caster. Problem is, I have some ideas for feat options, but I can't decide which ones are worth using:

Metamagic Specialist (Player Handbook 2): Lets me apply metamagic effects without increasing casting time. Could be helpful since blood quickening lets me use those without taking feats for them
Also: do the "spells known" listed under your Draconic Heritage mean you have the option of taking those spells, are forced to spend list slots on those spells, or get those spells in addition to your normal number of spells known?

Domain Access-Luck (Complete Champion): fits the theme, grants a free reroll, and gives access to some potentially useful spells like Aid and Miracle.

Dragonblood Sorcerer (Races of the Dragon): Allows different class feat options that would fit within my level plan and have some interesting-sounding bonuses, but I don't know if taking first level over Metamagic Specialist is better or not.

Luck Feats (Complete Scoundrel): I need one of these to get Fortune's Friend and get two extra for doing so, but I am not sure how much farther I should look into these. So far I'm thinking Lucky Catch, Magical Fortune, and Tempting Fate.

I just need professional advice for choosing this sort of thing, and could maybe take some suggestions if anyone has any other/better ideas.

Comment: At what levels you want this build to be played?

Comment: Levels 1-8 of Sorcerer, levels 9-13 of Fatespinner, levels 14-18 of Fortune's Friend, and the rest will probably go back to Sorcerer (though he still gets levels of Sorcerer from all of the Fatespinner and some of the Fortune's Friend levels).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with most Sorcerers, your spell selection is going to have a far greater effect on your character's playstyle than feats ever will. Once your Luck feat requirements have been satisfied, consider filling the rest up with general, Sorcerer-useful feats, like Versatile Spellcaster (as Swooper suggested), Arcane Thesis (Player's Handbook 2) coupled with Metamagic feats, reserve feats (Complete Mage) and so on.

Unluck (Spell Compendium) and Alter Fortune (Player's Handbook 2) come to mind as luck-themed spells.

As for luck feats:

- Lucky Start is definitely the first Luck feat I'd take. Initiative is one of the few rolls that consistently matters for a Sorcerer.
- Magical Fortune is OK, I guess.
- Tempting Fate is kind of planning to fail, but it's likely to save your butt *sometime*. So sure, why not.
- Lucky Catch is far too situational to be worth it.
- I'd consider Unbelievable Luck or Survivor's Luck next.

Domain Access: Luck is a complete trap. Notice how many spells known it costs you. You're losing one spell per (presumably spell) level, and only get the meager benefit of being able to cast one domain spell per spell level per day in return as far as spells are concerned.

Regarding your question about Draconic Heritage: If you're talking about the feat presented in Races of the Dragon and Complete Arcane, it doesn't add any spells known to your list. It's the Draconic Legacy feat that adds them.

Answer (score 3):

I notice [Versatile Spellcaster](http://www.realmshelps.net/cgi-bin/featbox.pl?feat=Versatile_Spellcaster) hasn't been mentioned yet. It's practically mandatory for spontaneous casters. Don't take it too early in the build though, but by mid-levels it's essential.

Comment: Ah, got it. Definitely taking that one. Would 9th level be a good time to take it?

Comment: At higher levels the way to quickly burn your spellslots if Arcane Spellsurge. Versatile Spellcaster could be combined with it, but is not economically effective for higher slots, so I think you will be using it for 2+2=3 or 3+3=4 tops. If you are to take it, level 9 seems about right.

Answer (score -1):

Metamagic specialist is a good ability if you'll be using plenty of metamagic feats, otherwise go with whatever familiar you find most appealing (raven for early warning system, snake for +3 bluff, etc).

I recommend keeping your sorceror class level low, since they get even less than wizards as far as leveling up goes. If you can qualify for other prestige classes to boost your spellcasting, take them over sorceror. Shouldn't be difficult at the levels you're talking.

Running with the gambler and support caster theme, I recommend going with **at least two levels of [prestige bard.](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/prestigiousCharacterClasses.htm#prestigeBard)** One grants you **access to some nice spells** you'd otherwise have to leave alone. Two grants a caster level. You'll be drawing from the sorceror and the bard list for which spells you wish to know, as well as spell completion and spell trigger items.

> The bard, paladin, and ranger spell lists contain a number of spells that don't appear on other classes' spell lists. **In general, any character who enters one of these prestige classes should gain access to spells unique to that class's spell list**, at the same levels indicated for the standard class.

*Freedom of movement, song of discord, and find the path* for starters. You can even **get ahold of some spells at lower levels,** like *legend lore.* Specifically not mentioned earlier because in my opinion they warrant their own section - cure spells. Light, moderate, serious and critical. Mass light and moderate, as well. Note that **you'll be losing a caster level at first level**. While your divination, enchantment and illusion caster level will rise by two, necromancy and evocation will drop by two. Seems in line with your goal, though. Because this is for a support caster, one lost caster level won't kill you.

**Ability to cast arcane spells freely in light armor, as well as many more skill points than the sorceror**, definitely supports this option too. Worth a look. Minimum skill points versus quite a few makes quite the difference, even if only a couple of levels worth. At any rate, it's got my vote higher than simply another level of sorceror.