# What are some good chance/luck-themed spells for Sorcerers?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, spells

I'm building a gambler-themed Spellscale Sorcerer, and I was wondering if anyone knew of any good luck-themed spells. I know there's things like Unluck and the various Prismatic/Rainbow spells (the ones with random effects), but what else is there that I might have missed?

Comment: Related: [Need help with Sorcerer build options](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/19085/need-help-with-sorcerer-build-options)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two *kinds* of "luck" spells that need to be considered.

## Rerolling

Anecdotally, as someone with *horrible* luck, having these are futile. Those of us on whom probability takes steaming dumps know that no reasonable number of rerolls will *ever* produce a satisfactory result (also known as the *lie of averages*), and having reroll abilities means expending resources that could've instead been devoted to *making others roll better* or *not having to roll at all*.

That said, here are some reroll spells and what gets rerolled.

### 1st-level Spells

- *cheat* (*SpC* 46): A dice roll *your character* makes in a game *he's* playing; weird, unique spell.

### 2nd-level Spells

- *insight of good fortune* (*PH2* 115): Attack roll, saving throw, or skill or ability check.

### 3rd-level Spells

- *alter fortune* (*PH2* 101): Any roll.
- *curse of the gypsies* (*Dragon* #348 75): Target's natural 20s.
- *unluck* (*SpC* 227): All target's die rolls.

### 4th-level Spells

- *battle hymn* (*SpC* 25): Will save.
- *cynosure* (*Dragon* #338 77): Accuracy with *plane shift* and *teleport* .

### 9th-level Spells

- *wish* (*PH* 302): Any roll.

That's... not a lot. As with most things magical, the Clr's ability to pick new spells from the thousands available makes him better at this than a Sor, and the Brd's seeming emphasis on wacky antics lets him access a few unique ones, too. Further, *Races of Destiny*'s spells *warp destiny* and *choose destiny* are *awesome* for this, but they are exclusively destiny Domain spells.

## Randomness

Arguably, any spell requiring a saving throw, attack roll, or damage roll is *random*. Assuming, however, that the spell's *effect* should be random, this could easily be a Sor's whole theme as there are so many. Note that *lesser confusion* is only on the Brd spell list and the madness Domain.

Anecdotally, these spells make other players hate you. Not your character--*he* didn't make these choices--*you*. That's because the resources you committed to doing *this* could have been spent doing something *reliable*. When you bring Swingy the Luckmaster to the table, expect dice thrown at you.

### 1st-level Spells

- *scramble true position* (*ToM* 258): Randomly teleport a group of foes; good luck with the truename component, though.

### 2nd-level Spells

- *channel the mishtai* (*Magic of Incarnum* 99): Have your body inhabited by a random soul. *Note:* Some souls are *terrible*.
- *feline distraction* (Random Encounters column "Ways of the Sword: Cat's Claw Dueling Pride"): Like *confusion* but *far* more embarrassing.
- *rainbow beam* (*SpC* 165): Random type of damage.
- *scattering trap* (*PH2* 123-4): Random short-range teleportation.

### 3rd-level Spells

- *prismatic mist* (*PH2* 121-2): Random effect; confusion's possible.
- *rain of terror* (*Dragon* #348 76): So, in a 100-ft. *radius* centered on you the sky rains random stuff (e.g. ash, blood, dead bats, spiders) to, ultimately, grant you a +10 bonus on Intimidate skill checks. That's a *long, awesome* way to go for a skill bonus. I love this spell.

### 4th-level Spells

- *confusion* (*PH* 212): A classic.
- *defenestrating sphere* (*SpC* 62): Randomly move the target toward a window; a spell surely created solely so the author could use the word *defenestrate*.
- *scramble portal* (*SpC* 181): O, the places they'll go!
- *siren's call* (*SW* 121-2): Target heads for the sea, or wanders randomly if he doesn't know where the sea is.

### 5th-level Spells

- *contact other plane* (*PH* 212-3): Sometimes an answer, sometimes a lie, and sometimes you can't cast spells for a month--*awesome!*
- *prismatic ray* (*SpC* 162): The poor man's *spray*.

### 6th-level Spells

- *guards and wards* (*PH* 237): In the right place--the tendriculos hedge maze protecting your castle, for instance--this is hilarious. The DM's expression when your party tries to map a similarly warded area isn't *nearly* as funny.

### 7th-level Spells

- *insanity* (*PH* 244): A not-funny funny spell.
- *prismatic eye* (*SpC* 161-2): It's a moist, apple-sized floating eye that shoots rainbows. Really. *Trivia:* When originally published this was a 6th-level spell but was changed to a 7th-level spell in the *SpC*--try to talk your DM into putting it at 6th-level again. I'm of the opinion that whoever bumped it up forgot about...
- *prismatic spray* (*PH* 264): The rich man's *ray*.

### 8th-level Spells

- *fimbulwinter* (*Fr* 93-4): Some days no wind blows and the snow melts, and other days there are 30+ MPH winds and *seven feet of snow!* Take that, nature!
- *mind of the labyrinth* (*DM* 70): It's like *mind blank* for the odd and inefficient.
- *prismatic wall* (*PH* 264-5): A classic.

### 9th-level Spells

- *prismatic sphere* (*PH* 264-5): The classic-est.
- *reality maelstrom* (*SpC* 168): O, the places they'll *all* go.

Comment: Since this got bumped, I want to take this opportunity to say that “_mind of the labyrinth_ (_DM_ 70): It's like _mind blank_ for the odd and inefficient,” remains one of my favorite lines on this entire site. I have this question favorited just for that.

Answer (score 3):

I’m away from my books and too busy to go digging besides, but there is *cheat* in *Spell Compendium* that lets you, well, cheat at games of chance (dice, roulette, and so on). I think it’s just a reroll though.